# Latex line-spacing and delete page

Tags: overleaf

I have found this [template](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/conlang-grammar-template/ysvrsjwftmfx) and I would like change some things. I have trieed, but it doesn't work. I want to add a little bit of line spacing in the title, I have added `\linespread{value} [file clgrammar, row 66]` but it is useless. How can I resolve this? Also, is it possible to delete the first page after the cover?

Comment: A few hints. / It's better to copy the (short) code, as links may lead to nowhere over time. / I suggest to get a book on Latex, e.g. from a library, or to have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX . Once you've got an idea about how Latex, you can find answers more easily. / Work on your set of questions separately. Copy said code, leave out what's irrelevant e.g. for the page-question, try something yourself and post your code then, showing where you struggle.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Since your question appears to pertain to a resource provided by Overleaf, have you considered contacting the Overleaf helpdesk? Their LaTeX support staff are top notch.

Comment: I have read L'arte di usare latex but I don't know how resolve in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to redefine the title page.

Add this code before `\begin{document}`

With `\fontsize{<font size>}{< line skip>}` you can change the size and the line skip of the title.

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{{\bfseries
        \thispagestyle{empty}\pagecolor{cover}
        \begin{center}
            \parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\fontsize{50}{80}\selectfont\textsc{\thetitle}} \\
            \vspace{1.5cm}
            {\Large\emph{\thesubtitle}} \\
            \vspace{1cm}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/cover.png}            
            \vfill
            \theauthor
        \end{center}
        \newpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}\pagecolor{background}           
}}
```

[image: a]

To delete the blank page after the cover use `\documentclass[oneside]{clgrammar}`

To get the right page numbering add `\frontmatter` before `\tableofcontents`

[image: b]

To be compiled with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass[oneside]{clgrammar}% changed <<<<<<<<<

\title{A Grammar of  Foo}

\author{J Rain De Jager}

    \renewcommand{\maketitle}{{\bfseries
            \thispagestyle{empty}\pagecolor{cover}
            \begin{center}
                \parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\fontsize{50}{80}\selectfont\textsc{\thetitle}} \\
                \vspace{1.5cm}
                {\Large\emph{\thesubtitle}} \\
                \vspace{1cm}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/cover.png}            
                \vfill
                \theauthor
            \end{center}
            \newpage
            \thispagestyle{empty}\pagecolor{background}           
    }}
            
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

Introduction, history, etc.

\chapter{Phonology} 
...
\end{document}
```